# What is the data type of a parameter that is a function?

Tags: python, function, type-hinting

When I create a function, I often specify the data types of its arguments, for example:

```
def my_func(name: str, surname: str) -> str:
       full_name = name + surname
       return full_name
```

but if an argument of a function is another function, what is its data type?

I tried to do this:

```
def my_func_2(func: function) -> str: 
    return func()
```

but I get

> NameError: name function is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You should find something useful in module `typing`.

```
def my_func_2(func: typing.Callable) -> str:
```

The cleanest solution is to import only `Callable` from the module, to prevent the function's prototype to be too long.

```
from typing import Callable

def my_func_2(func: Callable) -> str:
```